# Read the state of a checkbox in another method

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My `WPF` app has a  `MainWindow` class with a method called `ApplyButton_Click` which does a lot of calculation based on input from different boxes and gives the result to an output. Now I wish to take into the account the condition of a `CheckBox` in those calculation, having checked as the default state of the `CheckBox`.
Part of the `xaml` code is like this:

```
<Button x:Name="ApplyButton" Click="ApplyButton_Click" Content="apply" 
   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="300,200,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" 
   RenderTransformOrigin="0.2,4.0" Height="20"/>

<CheckBox x:Name = "my_checkBox" Content = "check_it" 
   HorizontalAlignment = "Left" Margin = "500,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment = "Top" 
   Width = "90" Checked = "HandleCheck" Unchecked = "HandleCheck"/>
```

and I my .cs code is as follows:

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window //, IDisposable
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
     InitializeComponent();
    }

private void HandleCheck_time(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
   if(my_checkBox.IsChecked == true) 
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Checkbox check is detected !");
   }

   if(my_checkBox.IsChecked == false) 
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Checkbox uncheck is detected !") ;
   }
}

private void ApplyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   bool click_val=(my_checkBox.IsChecked==true); // this is solved.
   if (click_val) 
   {
      Console.WriteLine("... then do a lot of things based on the state of the checkbox"); 
   }
}
}
}
```

In summary, I need to read the state of checkbox in my ApplyButton_Click method and have the checked state as the default state for the checkbox.

Comment: there was a reason for removing those tags from  the header. You are not supposed to add tags in the header

Comment: Btw, what you have provided is not complete, and I am not sure how to understand the _I wished this .cs code_... part.

Comment: You will need to pass a reference to each control in to the class where you want to access it.  Unfortunately, you haven't shared enough of your code to really be more specific than that.

Comment: @Iraj, me pointing you in the correct direction does not give any point.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Thank you. How can I reference more? and which part of the codes is needed? That's where my problem is. Before it is initialization and after it, there's big SQL query inside ApplyButton_Click class.

Comment: @Iraj To be the most helpful, we would need to see how the instance of your ".cs" class is created, and how it is used relative to the XAML.

Comment: Ok, based on your recent edits, your XAML and your .cs file represent the same class, so you don't need to pass any references around, you already have everything you need.  You should be able to tell if the box is checked by `if(my_checkBox.IsChecked){...}` from within the `ApplyButton_Click` method.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Yes, I can get it. But unfortunately I can't hand-in the result into my main class which is 'ApplyButton_Click'. That's because I'm generally inexperienced with classes.

Comment: `ApplyButton_Click` isn't a class, it's a method that is a member of the `MainWindow` class. `my_checkBox` is also a member of that same class, so you should have no problems reading the value of the checkbox directly from the event handler of the button.  If that isn't working, there must be some other difference between your actual code, and the code posted here, or the situation is more complex than you have described.  In which case, we'll need some more information again.

Comment: I have a meeting in a few minutes, but if you are willing to wait about an hour, I can create a very small example project for you that should show how to do what you are looking for.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Thank you very much for your help. It is solved now. I edited the code. Now the only left problem is that I wish to choose a default "checked" state for my checkbox.

Comment: That's easy, just add `IsChecked="true"` to the element in the XAML.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Fantastic! Thank you! You helped me a lot. 
If you wish you can post a short summary of your hints so that I can check "answered".